# How to set client side Folder path(Like D://new folder) for download file in spring contoller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-data

I have one spring controller, I want to download file in specific path like D:// or K://, But right now it will be download in downloads folder by default.
I am taking my file from **/WEB-INF/ folder** (server side located in Tomcat folder) and i want to write in client machine D:\ drive  please see my below code is something wrong please let me know. I am using google crome. 
Thanks in Advance

```
 public void downloadFile(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
            //ServletContext context = request.getServletContext();
            String filePath = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/") + "/"+"out.json";

             // get absolute path of the application
            ServletContext context = request.getServletContext();
            String appPath = context.getRealPath("");
            System.out.println("appPath = " + appPath);

            // construct the complete absolute path of the file
            //String fullPath = appPath + filePath;      
            File downloadFile = new File(filePath);
            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(downloadFile);

            // get MIME type of the file
            String mimeType = context.getMimeType(filePath);
            if (mimeType == null) {
                // set to binary type if MIME mapping not found
                mimeType = "application/octet-stream";
            }
            System.out.println("MIME type: " + mimeType);

            // set content attributes for the response
            response.setContentType(mimeType);
            response.setContentLength((int) downloadFile.length());

            // set headers for the response
            String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
            String headerValue = String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"",
                    downloadFile.getName());
            System.out.println("downloadFile.getName()" + downloadFile.getName());
            response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);

            // get output stream of the response
            OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            int bytesRead = -1;

            // write bytes read from the input stream into the output stream
            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                outStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }

            inputStream.close();
            outStream.close();
        }
```

Comment: Browsers don't work that way, by design. You cannot do what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot decide where the client will save the downloaded file on server side - in fact, you cannot even affect whether it will save it anywhere at all! That's for the client (e.g. Chrome) to decide.

See [Chrome help](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95574?hl=en) for how to change default download location in Chrome.

Comment: actually Client send his folder location.. we only want to download file that location.